# Laravel upgrade issue with whereHas

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I recently changed versions of Laravel and I am now getting this error:

```
LogicException
Has method invalid on "belongsTo" relations.
```

Can anyone explain why I am now getting this error?

If I comment out the below three lines, no error.

Version: `"laravel/framework": "4.1.7"`

The piece of code in question is this:

```
        $orderCount->whereHas('order', function($query) {
            $query->whereRaw("status IN ('pending', 'prepaid')");
        });
```

The entire controller logic here:

```
public function show($id) {

    // the fields we want back
    $fields = array('id', 'title', 'description', 'msrp', 'brand_id', 'category_id');

    // how many products are in pending orders
    $orders = 0;

    // assume not admin must be display = 1
    $display = 1;

    // if logged in add more fields
    if(Auth::check()) {

        // add these fields to the query if dealer
        array_push($fields, 'price_dealer', 'quantity');

        // if admin add these fields
        if (Session::get("admin")) {
            $display = 0;
            array_push($fields,  'cost', 'display', 'crate_quantity_threshold', 'price_crate');
        }
    }

    $product = Product::with('images', 'brand', 'category', 'docs')
        ->select($fields)
        ->where('display', '>=', $display)
        ->find($id);

    if(Auth::check()) {

        // make orders obj
        // we need to see how many orders
        // there are pending for this product
        $obj = new OrderItem;
        $orderCount = $obj->newQuery();
        $orderCount->where('product_id', '=', $id);
        $orderCount->whereHas('order', function($query) {
            $query->whereRaw("status IN ('pending', 'prepaid')");
        });
        $product->orders = $orderCount->sum('quantity') > 0 ? $orderCount->sum('quantity') : 0;
        // dd(\DB::getQueryLog());
    }

    if ($product) {
        return Response::json(array(
            'product' => json_decode($product)
                ),
            200
        );
    } else {
        return Response::json(array(
            'flash' => "Not found"
                ),
            500
        );
    }

}
```

In Order model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'order_items', 'order_id', 'product_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Upgrade to 4.1.11+ due to:

[4.1.7](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.1.7/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php#L88) - not implemented method

[4.1.11](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v4.1.11/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php#L93) - method in place

Comment: This is what did later that night. Actually, went to 4.1.12. I am also specifying versions in my composer.json to avoid this in the future. Thanks!